# Can I reuse adminhtml UI compontent on frontend? if so How?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, uicomponent, extension-attributes

I'm new to Magento, hope this is the right place to ask this question, well the thing is that I'm new to Magento 2 and I'm trying to see how everything works, I bought a Module that converts Magento 2 into a marketplace, but now I have the dilemma that they won't allow me to show the "Attribute sets" on the vendor side, I can see them just in the admin, but not in the vendor site, they want to sell me that as a separate plugin.

I don't want to buy a new plugin, so I've been seeing how the admin side works for creating knew products, and I was thinking that maybe I could take that UI component (product_form) and put it on the frontend then "intercept" the method when the product is being created and then add that to the marketplace table, that way I wouldn't have to buy that plugin, but I don't know if this can be done and if so, where can I get specific info on how to do that? Is it worth it?

Thanks!